# Changing Range Breaks Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I need to off set the First row, so I Changed the range in the Sub from

```
For Each rng In Sheets("360").Range("B:CJ" & Lastrow)
```

to

```
For Each rng In Sheets("360").Range("B2:CJ2" & Lastrow)
```

The sub know barley runs it took 5 seconds to run and know takes minutes if it even finishes

How to fix this?

Thanks

```
Sub CleanAll()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    With Sheets("360")
        Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Each rng In Sheets("360").Range("B2:CJ" & Lastrow)
        rng.Value = NumberOnly(rng.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

The Function

```
Function NumberOnly(strSource As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strResult As String

For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
        Case 32, 48 To 57, 65, 78:
            strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
    End Select
Next
NumberOnly = strResult

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
For Each rng In Sheets("360").Range("B2:CJ2" & Lastrow)
```

Remove the 2 following CJ like this :

```
For Each rng In Sheets("360").Range("B2:CJ" & Lastrow)
```

Lastrow already designates the last row number so if Lastrow value is 300 and you write "CJ2" & Lastrow, your actual range is now B2:CJ2300 which means you're now running 2000 more rows.

Comment: I think you are right, but it's confusing as @Tim does it both ways in his question. +1

Comment: @DougGlancy Good point, I didn't realized it was ok in the CleanAll Sub. Yet that would explain why the Sub suddenly became much longer to run. +1

Comment: Marshall thanks for the response. So `For Each rng In Sheets("360").Range("B2:CJ" & Lastrow)` off sets the first row `from B2 to CJ2`? i.e the first row is not acted on by the Sub

Comment: I'm not sure I umderstand what you want : B2:CJ50 will select rows from 2 to 50 so it will skip the first line (A1:CJ12)

Answer (score 1):

I find that using your data in tables will solve A LOT of re-sizing range issues.

That being said, you should create a variant array from your range and then loop through the variant array. Once done copy to array back to the range. This will speed it up a hundredfold.

Something like this...

```
Sub CleanAll()

    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim Lastrow As Long


    With Sheets("360")
        Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    myArray = Sheets("360").Range("B2:CJ" & Lastrow)

    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        For y = LBound(myArray, 2) To UBound(myArray, 2)
            myArray(x, y) = NumberOnly(myArray(x, y))
        Next y
    Next x

    Sheets("360").Range("B2:CJ" & Lastrow) = myArray
End Sub

Function NumberOnly(ByVal strSource As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strResult As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 32, 48 To 57, 65, 78:
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    NumberOnly = strResult

End Function
```

Comment: jlaverde, I would like to use your code but I get `ByRef argument type mismatch` when I run it the `myArray(X, y) = NumberOnly(myArray(X, y))` the second `myArray(X, y)` is high lighted in blue

Comment: make the formal parameter of NumberOnly Function byVal I'll edit my answer.